# Spring MVC ExceptionHandling: action annotated as @ExceptionHandling can't pass variable to error view

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, spring-mvc, exception

I know a lot of people have had issues similar to this.Sorry posting it again, but i believe there is something i might not be doing well.

I'm using `Spring 3.0.5` with `freemarker 2.3.14`. Basically i wanted to show a friendly error message to the user.

```
@Controller("exceptioncontroller")
public class ExceptionController {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/site/contentnofoundexception")
public String throwContentFileNotFound(){
    boolean exception = true;
    if(exception){
        throw new ContentFileNotFoundException("content ZZZ123 not found");
    }
    return  "errortest";
}


@ExceptionHandler(value = ContentFileNotFoundException.class)
public String handleFileNotFoundException(ContentFileNotFoundException ex, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("msg",ex.getErrorMessage());//this message is never passed to the error view. msg is always null 
    return "error";
 }
}


//same issue for handleException action which uses ModelAndView
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex){
   logger.error(ex);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("error");
    String message = "Something Broke. Please try again later";
    mv.addObject("msg", message);
    return mv;
} 

 // Custom Exception class   
 public class ContentFileNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

 private String errorMessage;

 public ContentFileNotFoundException(String message) {
    this.setErrorMessage(message);
 }

 public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
 }

 public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
     this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
 }
}
```

So each case either `handleFileNotFoundException` or `handleException` actions are called alright but they can't send any message to the `error.ftl` view to display to the user. Is there anything i need to configure?

Thanks for helping in advance